# Compilar java e gerar o .jar

Tags: java

Estou com um projeto maven já bem estruturado. Quero criar o .jar para rodar a aplicação.

Dentro do projeto, no prompt, fiz:

```
mvn clean install package
```

Retorna o erro:

> C:\exemploSpring\portal-de-inscricao\portal-api>mvn package
>
> [INFO] Scanning for projects... [INFO] [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Building Portal Api 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources
>   (default-resources) @ portal-api  --- [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to
>   copy filtered resources. [INFO] Copying 1 resource [INFO] Copying 1
>   resource [INFO] [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
>   (default-compile) @ portal-api --- [INFO] Changes detected -
>   recompiling the module! [INFO] Compiling 65 source files to
>   C:\exemploSpring\portal-de-inscricao\portal- api\target\classes [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] BUILD FAILURE [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [INFO] Total time: 9.585 s [INFO] Finished at:
>   2015-09-03T10:39:59-03:00 [INFO] Final Memory: 10M/25M [INFO]
>   ------------------------------------------------------------------------ [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3. 1:compile
>   (default-compile) on project portal-api: Fatal error compiling: invali
>   d target release: 1.8 -> [Help 1] [ERROR] [ERROR] To see the full
>   stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e swit ch. [ERROR]
>   Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging. [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions,
>   please rea d the following articles: [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionE
>   xception
>
> C:\exemploSpring\portal-de-inscricao\portal-api>

Comment: Parece algum erro com a versão do Java, ou ainda a JAVA_HOME pode não estar setada para a sessão atual. Tente antes de rodar o comando citado, verificar a versão do Java. Se tudo estiver Ok, dentro do POM verifique a versão target do projeto, no maven-build-plugin. Caso não encontre, poste o seu POM.

Comment: @Celso Marigo Jr

A linha mensionada não encontrei. Encontrei o seguinte:

  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <start-class>com.dendetech.application.Application</start-class>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>
 <build>
A versão que eu uso é 7. Aqui está como 8. Este projeto foi clonado do gitbucket. Vou mudar a versão e posto qualquer coisa.

Comment: Tá parecendo que você tem configurado no pom para compilar na versão 8 e você não tem a versão 8 do Java. Coloca o seu pom.xml ai por favor. Aproveita e executa java -version no terminal também.

Comment: @Fabio H. Gonzales Barbosa

Postarei em vários comentários, devido a restrição de limites de caracteres.

Comment: <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <groupId>com.dendetech</groupId>
 <artifactId>portal-api</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <name>Portal Api</name>
 <description>Portal APi</description>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
 </parent>

Comment: <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>mysql</groupId>
   <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>4.3.10.Final</version>
  </dependency>

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
   <version>4.0.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

Comment: <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <start-class>com.dendetech.application.Application</start-class>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>

Comment: <build>
  <pluginManagement>
   <plugins>
    <plugin>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </plugin>

   </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
</project>

Comment: bA versão do java aqui é 7. Eu posso alterar neste arquivo a versão, ou indo na propriedade do projeto e mudando para a versão correta e na compilação o java reconheça?

Comment: André no teu pom. está especificado para compilar teu projeto com Java 8, e teu Java é o 7. Te aconselho a fazer o seguinte, se você não tiver nenhum código que compila só no Java 8 troca no teu pom o <java.version> para 1.7 ou troca o seu JAVA_HOME para apontar para um Java 8.

Se você for na propriedade do projeto e trocar para Java 7 por exemplo, quando você buildar o projeto ele vai mudar para 8 de novo conforme seu pom.xml.

Comment: Se resolver teu problema eu coloco uma resposta abaixo ;)